# how to get the local pc name from a remotely hosted portal using php

Tags: php, mysql, remote-server

I have a project support desk which is running on wamp server remotely [image]

Other user can acces this url on other computer for submitting problem,i need to get the computer name of the local pc which user accessing,currently i am geeting the computer name of my pc because the project is hosted on my system and i make the wamp remotely

since they are accessing the remote ip of my system my computer name is getting instead of user local system and ip

```
GetHostByName($REMOTE_ADDR);
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);  
$user = $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
```

I tried this coded but my pc name is coming.

Comment: Does the webserver retrieve the computer name? You can check var_dump($_ENV) and var_dump($_SERVER), but I think you will need javascript to fetch this environment variable from the client.

Comment: yes fetching the computer name,but its my pc name